# how to show that the quadratic function strongly convex iff A positive definite and parameter min eigenvalue?

Tags: convex-analysis, convex-optimization, non-convex-optimization

I have the following question:

> Show that the quadratic function $$f(x) = x^T Ax+2b^T x+c$$ with $$A = A^T ∈ R^{n×n}, b ∈ R^n, c ∈ R$$ is strongly convex if and only if $$A ≻ 0$$, and in that case the strong convexity parameter is $$2λ_{min}(A)$$.

I know that strong convexity means $$f(x) - \frac{\sigma}{2} \|x \|^2$$ is also convex.

Comment: Do you know of the Hessian criterion for (strong) convexity or do you have to show this from first principles?

Comment: @VHarisop No, the book does not mention that, so I guess it would be better to show it. But if it takes too much time, then I we can directly refer to that theorem (criterion)

Comment: I see. What other tools do you have at your disposal? For example, does your book mention that a differentiable $f$ is strongly convex if and only if $(\nabla f(x) - \nabla f(y))^{\top}(x - y) \geq \sigma \| x - y\|^2$?

Comment: @VHarisop yes the last inequality that you mentioned can be used. also we have $$f(y) \geq f(x)+ \nabla f(x)^T (y-x) + \frac{\sigma}{2} \| x-y\|^2$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A differentiable function $f$ is $\sigma$-strongly convex if and only if

$$
(\nabla f(x) - \nabla f(y))^{\top}(x - y) \geq \sigma \lVert x - y \rVert^2.
$$

In your case, $\nabla f(x) = 2Ax + 2b$. Replacing in the above inequality, you obtain

$$
(\nabla f(x) - \nabla f(y)) = 2A(x - y) \Rightarrow
(\nabla f(x) - \nabla f(y))^{\top}(x - y) = 2(x - y)^{\top} A (x - y).
$$

The only way for this to be strictly positive for all $x, y$ (with $x \neq y$) is if $A \succ 0$. In that case, the modulus of strong convexity follows easily from the definition of the minimum eigenvalue.